# Liquidbase add a column with a value from anouther tabke

Tags: liquibase

I want to add 2 columns in the existing table `T_CALL_USER_ANSWER` with the values off the related table `T_CALL`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
    <property name="getState" value="SELECT c.state FROM T_CALL c WHERE c.callid = call_id"/>
    <property name="getTenant" value="SELECT c.tenant_id FROM T_CALL c WHERE c.callid = call_id"/>
    <changeSet id="2023_11_10_09-00_update_for_logbook_part2" author="tkocher">
        <addColumn tableName="T_CALL_USER_ANSWER">
            <column name="call_state" type="VARCHAR(50)" defaultValueComputed="${getState}"></column>
            <column name="tenant_id" type="BIGINT" defaultValueComputed="${getTenant}"></column>
        </addColumn>
    </changeSet>
```

Failed with

> ested exception is liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Error parsing line 2 column 6 of classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/2023_11_09_09-00_update_for_logbook_part2.xml: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)

Does somebody know what I did wrong?

Comment: Well for one - that XML isn't valid - you have `<databaseChangeLog>` opening tag - but not closing tag (at least not shown)